# ¿Cómo mostrar respuestas de comentarios?

Tags: php, mysql

He creado un blog con comentarios y ahora quiero añadirle respuestas, es decir, que si alguien comenta, yo pueda responder a ese comentario y que aparezca debajo de su comentario. Y que se pueda seguir respondiendo a esa respuesta y siga apareciendo en lista debajo. Si hay más comentarios, el siguiente aparecerá después de la última respuesta, vamos, lo típico de todos los blog.

El código siguiente pinta los comentarios que tengo en mysql, y añade la palabra **responder** que al pulsarla carga el formulario que guarda las respuestas en mysql. Hasta aquí todo funciona bien.

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment):?>                        
    <div class='commentList' id="<?php echo $comment['idcom']; ?>">
    <div class='nameComment'>                               
        <p><?php echo $comment['name'];?><span><?php echo $comment['fechacomentario']; ?></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class='textComment'>
        <p><?php echo $comment['comment'];?></p>
    </div>
    </div>    
                                     
    <div class="responderComment_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>">
        <a id="formularioRespuesta_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>" class="responderText" onclick="abrirFormularioRes(this.id)">Responder</a>
    <div id="cargarFomulario_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>" class="respuestas"></div>                        
    </div>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Este foreach pinta la respuestas.

```
              <?php foreach ($comments as $res):?>
                    <div class='resList'>
                    <div class='nameComment'>                               
                        <p><?php echo $res['nameres'];?><span><?php echo $res['fecharespuesta']; ?></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='textComment'>
                        <p><?php echo $res['respuesta'];?></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Tengo 3 tablas: post, comments, respuestas.

1. En **comentarios** incluyo una columna que me guarda el id del post
   donde se ha hecho el comentario.
2. En **respuestas** incluyo otra columna que me guarda el id del comentario al que se le ha respondido.

**PROBLEMAS**

No se como hacer un foreach para mostrar las respuestas debajo de los comentarios. He probado poner el foreach de respuestas dentro del foreach de comentarios pero no funciona

Con esta consulta y creando 2 **foreach** uno para comentarios y otro para respuestas, consigo que me los muestre por separado, pero la idea es que cada respuesta salga debajo de su comentario.

```
SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN post ON (comments.idpost = post.id) AND post.id = '{$_SESSION['pageid']}' INNER JOIN respuestas ON (respuestas.idcomentario = comments.idcom) AND respuestas.idcomentario = idcomentario
```

¿Alguien me puede guiar para mostrar cada respuesta debajo de su comentario?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sin mayúsculas sostenidas funciona mucho mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Perdón, no me he dado cuenta y lo sabía.

Comment: El camino sería, dentro del foreach de comentarios, para cada comentario, buscar en el array de respuestas las que tienen el id de comentario correspondiente y pintarlos. No es foreach porque no son toooodos y recorrerlos todos para pintar unos cuantos no sería óptimo

Comment: Gracias!! Voy a ver si consigo algo, sino vuelvo por aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Al final he encontrado otro camino para dar solución al problema que tenía ya que no conseguía hacer lo que me comentaba **Cesar** del array con un índice aunque si he utilizado parte de la estructura que me dio en su respuesta.

He realizado 2 consultas diferentes:

1. Consulta a comentarios filtrando por id del post.

   SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN post ON (comments.idpost = post.id) AND post.id = '{$_SESSION['pageid']}'
2. Consulta a respuestas que tienen el mismo id del comentario. Las respuestas tienen un campo en la BBDD que guarda el id del comentario al que responden.

   SELECT * FROM respuestas INNER JOIN comments ON (respuestas.idcomentario = comments.idcom)

Después utilizando la estructura de la anterior respuesta:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    // muestro comentarios
   
    foreach($respuestas as $res) {
        // cosas de respuestas
    }
}
```

He añadido una variable para sacar el **id** del comentario después de realizar el foreach de comentarios:

```
$idcom = $comment['idcom'];
```

Y otra variable dentro del foreach de respuestas:

```
$idcomentres = $res['idcomentario'];
```

Dentro del **foreach de respuestas** he incluido una condicional comparando que las dos variables tienen que ser iguales para mostrar la respuesta, sino no se muestra nada, es decir, no hay respuesta a ese comentario.

```
if ($idcom === $idcomentres) {
} else {
    //nada
}
```

Y aquí pongo como ha quedado el código final que me muestra los comentarios con sus respuestas debajo como yo quería :D

```
foreach($Comments as $comment) { 
    // muestro comentarios ?>
    <div class='commentList' id="<?php echo $comment['idcom']; ?>">
       <div class='nameComment'>                                
          <p><?php echo $comment['name'];?><span><?php echo $comment['fechacomentario']; ?></span></p>
       </div>
       <div class='textComment'>
         <p><?php echo $comment['comment'];?></p>
       </div>
    </div>
<?php                       
                        
$idcom = $comment['idcom'];                     

foreach($resultListadoRespuestas as $res) { 
    $idcomentres = $res['idcomentario'];
    if ($idcom === $idcomentres) { ?>
    <div class='resList'>
       <div class='nameComment'>                                
         <p><?php echo $res['nameres'];?><span><?php echo $res['fecharespuesta']; ?></span></p>
       </div>
       <div class='textComment'>
         <p><?php echo $res['respuesta'];?></p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    } else {
      //nada
    }
} ?>                    
<div class="responderComment_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>">
    <a id="formularioRespuesta_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>" class="responderText" onclick="abrirFormularioRes(this.id)">Responder</a>
<div id="cargarFomulario_<?php echo $comment['idcom'];?>" class="respuestas"></div>                        
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Gracias **Cesar** y **Alfabravo** por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal estás separando las respuestas de los comentarios en dos arrays. Lo suyo sería que tengas un array tipo árbol, osea un solo array con todos los comentarios. Cada comentario tendría un índice llamado `respuestas` y ahí agregarías un array con todas las respuestas. De ese modo te funcionaría con dos bucles.

Ejemplo:

```
$comentarios = [
    ['autor' => 'alguien',
    'contenido' => 'hola',
    'respuestas' => [ // este comentario tiene respuesta
        'autor' => 'otro',
        'contenido' => 'mundo?'
    ]],
    ['autor' => 'anonimo',
    'contenido' => 'no respondan a este comentario',
    'respuestas' => [] // este comentario no tiene respuestas
    ]
    // etc...
];
```

Con esos datos como ejemplo ya podrías hacer el bucle:

```
foreach($comentarios as $comentario) {
    // cosas de comentarios
    // ...

    // Si la key 'respuestas' del comentario es un array vacio
    // este foreach se obvia y continua con el bucle principal
    foreach($comentario['respuestas'] as $respuesta) {
        // cosas de respuestas
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por responder.
No se como empezar para crear el array con el índice. Para crear el array supongo que tendré que extraer los datos de la BBDD pero no lo consigo.
Creo que la consulta que hago tampoco es la adecuada. La verdad que estoy bastante perdido ahora mismo :(

Comment: Sin crear el índice que me dices, consigo mostrar el primer comentario y debajo aparecen todas las respuestas, tanto de ese comentario como el de otros pero no muestra otros comentarios. Supongo que creando el índice se mostrará bien pero no consigo hacerlo.